# How to find folder when drive letter is unknown and folder path is random/unknown. using wmic logicaldisk get caption in Batch File?

Tags: batch-file, directory, path, find, drive-letter

Condition:

I have 3 different folders. `Folder1`, `Folder2` and `Folder 3`.

They are placed within an unknown USB drive.

Also the path is random.

Sometimes it's:

```
G:\Hello\Folder1
G:\Hello\Folder2
G:\hello\Folder3
```

and sometimes it's:

```
k:\Man\Google\Hey\Folder1
k:\Man\Google\Hey\Folder2
k:\Man\Google\Hey\Folder3
```

Means they are exist in random driver letters and also want to find with any random subfolder.

I used:

```
@echo off
for %%a in (C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) do (
    if exist %%a:\HOPE\EXTRA\Folder1 (
        goto true
    )
)
```

Here I don't want use `(C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z)` because `cmd` shows an error when driver letter is found but voume not mounted.

So I used following script

```
@echo off
CLS&ECHO.&ECHO   Vol Access   Type
echo.
SET "DVF="

FOR /F "tokens=1,*" %%A IN ('wmic logicaldisk get caption^, description ^| FIND ":"') DO (
    VOL %%A >nul 2>&1 && (
        CALL SET "DVF=%%DVF%% %%A"& ECHO   %%A ^| ON.  %%B) || (
            ECHO   %%A ^| OFF. %%B
        )
    )   
ECHO.
ECHO.
ECHO  Available Volumes: %DVF%
echo.
echo.
TIMEOUT /T 5
```

I want to find `Folder1`, `Folder2` and `folder 3` from  available volumes, but here output of `%DVF%` is  `C: D: K: G:`

So I want to search each available volumes to find those 3 folders are available in 1 volume and then `set` that drive = `%foldervol%`, or something, for next code or `goto next`

So can anyone help me using same script I mentioned here?

I want to find all three folders from unknown available volumes then echo folders found at volumename and goto next?

Comment: According to [this post on Super User](https://superuser.com/a/1074866), you should use the property `DeviceID` rather than `Caption`…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Questions should be limited to one problem only and the following should address that which is considered  your primary issue, i.e. to output your USB drive letters. It will not search for, or locate your directories, as that is a completely different problem for which you've provided no code or other indication of a self attempt.

```sh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions

For /F Tokens^=2^ Delims^=^" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe
 DiskDrive Where "InterfaceType='USB'" Assoc:List
 /AssocClass:Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition 2^>NUL ^|
 %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe "__R"') Do For /F Tokens^=4^ Delims^=^" %%H In (
    '%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe Path Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition
     2^>NUL ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe "%%G"') Do Echo %%H

%SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /T 5 /NoBreak 1>NUL
```

You would obviously replace `Echo %%H` on line `9` with your 'folder' search code, using `%%H\` as the root directory for each returned USB drive.